# How to access wash out soap actions directly with passing action name in query string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, wash-out

Here is my problem: One of our client wants to access soap actions with passing action_name in query string. Is it possible to do it with [wash_out](https://github.com/inossidabile/wash_out) gem?

**example url:**  http://example.com/dummy_soap/action?action_name=do_something

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible.  Use `send` to call the action that you want.  Note that this will only work if the other action explicitly calls `render` at the end of the action. Also, do not trust the :action_name param.  Consider checking the :action_name against a whitelist of allowed actions before using it and raise an error if it's invalid.

```
class DummySoapController < ApplicationController
  soap_service namespace: 'urn:WashOut'

  def action
    send(params[:action_name])
  end

  soap_action "convert_to_string", :args => :integer, :return => :string

  def convert_to_string
    render :soap => params[:value].to_s
  end

  soap_action "convert_to_integer", :args => :integer, :return => :float

  def convert_to_float
    render :soap => params[:value].to_f
  end

end
```

For example, to get a string value you would use the URL

http://example.com/dummy_soap/action?action_name=convert_to_string&value=1

Or to get a float

http://example.com/dummy_soap/action?action_name=convert_to_float&value=1